# Why it is difficult to find Chicago Screws smaller than M4 size?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I see most of them are of size M4, M5 or above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a shopping question. See [on-topic](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I disagree. I also asked an academic reason for the non-existence of Chicago Screws smaller than M4. If you don't like my question, you don't need to follow this thread.

Comment: It's not a thread.  It's a q&a site. You didn't even go for what engineering reason prevents the manufacturing chicargo screws under M4.

Comment: Never heard of Chicago Screws in my life. I have heard of barrel bolts, aka aircraft panel fasteners. Nelsen structural panel fasteners was a major brand.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly common that most non high speciality outfits do not carry screws smaller than M3-4 size. Chicago screws or not. I mean try shopping for a screw in size M1 and smaller.

The reason seems to be mostly economical. There is fairly low demand for these yet the cost of each screw is dominated by making them at all so they arent exactly cheap, for their weight anyway.

Could one be made? Well sure, I have made a 4 mm outer diameter one so about M3 size range (at the cost of ~10€ each). But since i dont have a swiss lathe, anything smaller and im severely limitted in length.

Consider using a rivet instead.